# genStrAsCharArray optimisation benefits

Tags: optimization, jsp, jboss

I am looking into the options available to me for optimising the performance of JBoss 5.1.0.

One of the options I am looking at is setting `genStrAsCharArray` to `true` in `<JBOSS_HOME>/server/<PROFILE>/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml`. This affects the generation of .java code from .JSPs.

The comment describes this flag as:

> Should text strings be generated as char arrays, to improve performance in some cases?

I have a few questions about this.

1. Is this the generation of Strings in the dynamic parts of the JSP page (ie each time the page is called) or is it the generation of Strings in the static parts (ie when the .java is built from the JSP)?
2. "in some cases" - which cases are these? What are the situations where the performance is worse?
3. Does this speed up the generation of the .java, the compilation of the .class or the execution of the .class?
4. At a more technical level (and the answer to this will probably depend on the answer to part 1), why can the use of char arrays improve performance?

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this setting all `String` values are declared as `static char[]` as follows:

```
static char[] _char_array_1 = "someString".toCharArray();
```

and used as follows:

```
out.write(_char_array_1);
```

instead of being used as follows:

```
out.write("someString");
```

This has two clear benefits:

1. A `char[]` has less memory overhead than `String`.
2. The `toCharArray()` doesn't need to be (implicitly) called on every `out.write(string)` anymore.

Sounds like microoptimization, but those little bits counts a lot in a heavily visited website.

This setting is by the way not JBoss AS specific. It's [Jasper](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) specific, the JSP compiler of Apache Tomcat which is also used in under each JBoss AS and Sun Glassfish.

Comment: When you say, With this setting all String values are declared as static char[], I assume you mean in the Java source that is generated from the JSP?

Comment: You explain the case where it is faster. But in what cases would it be slower or have other disadvantages?

Comment: @Jimmy: no one case. At least not in the JSP engine. If you were to do it in custom code, then it will become useless when you do at some point `new String(_char_array_1)`.